# array to js function from sql row

Tags: javascript, php

i have an sql with 2 columns, `latitude` and `longitude`.

I am able to print out the entries of these two columns like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo $row['latitude'];
    echo $row['longitude'];

}
```

I also have a JS function, where i need a `while` to add as many JS lines as the sql query returns. Here is the JS:

```
var myMarkers = {"markers": [
{"latitude": "47.47256859162068", "longitude":"19.055979251861572", "icon": "marker.png", "baloon_text": 'This is <strong>Budapest</strong>'},
]
};
```

So i'd need something like: `"latitude": $latitude[i]` and `"longitude": $longitude[i]` all these in a `for` or a `while`

Is there a way that i could pass the content of the two sql rows to a js function, to be able to get all the line with the correct values?

Comment: JSON encode it on the server and parse it on the client

Comment: Where does the value for `ballon_text` come from? Is it in the same database as lat long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the result of mysql data array into JSON.

```
$result_json = json_encode($result);
```

And parse this variable in `jQuery fashion` to access all values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj= $.parseJSON('<?= $result_json; ?>'); //Parse the above encoded Json.
    //Here is how you iterate
    var json = $.parseJSON(obj);
    $(json).each(function(i,val){
        console.log(val);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

An example of what to do can be [seen here](http://thisinterestsme.com/passing-php-array-javascript/).

Convert the data into JSON.

```
$markers = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $markers[] = array(
        'longitude' => $row['longitude'],
        'latitude' => $row['latitude']
    );
}
$markersJson = json_encode($markers);
```

Then pass it to your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $markersJson ; ?>');
    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Check your console to view the structure of the data.

Comment: Why there is need to create an empty array $markers when things can be done without creating it ?

Comment: @Vivek Readability. Also allows me to narrow down the amount of columns if I need to.

Comment: @Vivek Updated my answer to show you what I meant. My first approach was a tad bit "lazy". :)

Comment: is JSON.parse needed when printing an object declaration? Either way, ballon_text data needs to be included, though OP has not said where this data comes from

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your data through the SQL query and put the output in a single array via your loop.
Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to serialise the array into a transportable form, pass it to JavaScript, for example by an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and parse it in JS with the internal `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
<script>
var myMarkers = {"markers": [

<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>

    {"latitude": "<?php echo $row['latitude'];?>", "longitude":"<?php echo $row['longitude'];?>", "icon": "marker.png", "baloon_text": 'This is <strong>Budapest</strong>'},
<?php
}
?>
]
};
</script>
```

PHP is a server side language so it gets executed before javascript which is a client side language, the trick is to use :

```
"latitude": <?php echo $latitude[i];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<script>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events");
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{   
?>
var myMarkers[<?php echo $i;?>] = {"markers": [{"latitude": "<?php echo $row['latitude'];?>", "longitude":"<?php echo $row['longitude'];?>", "icon": "marker.png", "baloon_text": 'This is <strong>Budapest</strong>'},]};
<?php
    $i+=1;
}
?>
</script>
```